# How to add two or more resource in Server.xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, tomcat, server

I am trying to add two resource configuration in Server.xml file
with name test1 and test2.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource auth="Container"
        name="jdbc/test1"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="xxxxxx"
        username="xxxxx"
        password="xxxxx"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        initialSize="40"
        maxActive="-2"
        maxIdle="40"
        maxWait="10000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="25"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="150"
        minSpareThreads="25"
        maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="false"
        acceptCount="100"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="1024"
        noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
        factory="xxxxxxxx" />

<Resource auth="Container"
        name="jdbc/test2"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="yyyyyy"
        username="yyyyyy"
        password="yyyyyyyyy"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        initialSize="40"
        maxActive="-2"
        maxIdle="40"
        maxWait="10000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="25"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
        maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
        maxThreads="150"
        minSpareThreads="25"
        maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="false"
        acceptCount="100"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="1024"
        noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
        factory="xxxxxxxx" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

But when I try to get context

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/test2");
```

I am getting following error

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [test2] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [test2].
```

I am not sure if I am doing it correct or not. Can anyone help me adding two resources in server.xml file so tat I should be able to connect to two different databases. 
Thank you!

Comment: Are there any other errors in the log file -- perhaps the server log and not the application log? If the resource wasn't created successfully, it won't be found, later. Tomcat definitely supports multiple `<Resource>` elements as far back as Tomcat 4.x -- I've been using two of them in production for more than 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using multiple resource in tomcat.

Maybe it is a bug in tomcat container.

Alternative solution.

I defined the second resource in a application manage connection.

Hibernate Config Snippet:
>property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
>property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property> 
>property name="connection.username">user